# NoClassDefFoundError Java (wrong name)

Tags: java, exception, package

I've seen questions like this on here, but I can't find one that is specific to my situation, so sorry if this is a worn out question.

I've got a class P that is part of a package myname.utils located in ~/JavaClasses/myname/utils. I've got another class Printing that is not declared as a part of any package but is located in ~/JavaClasses/myname/practice. Class Printing imports class P. Both of these classes compile fine from ~/JavaClasses directory. However when I attempt to run the compiled class Printing like this

```
~/JavaClasses$ java myname/practice/Printing
```

I get the following errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: myname/practice/Printing (wrong name: Printing)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

Comment: It should be `java myname.practice.Printing`, assuming it's in a package named `myname.practice`.

Comment: Get a copy of class P, put it in your package, and add a `package` statement in the beginning to mark it as belonging to your package. Then, everything should work fine.

Comment: Do you have source code for any of this??

Answer (score 1):

The error *is not* related to *myname.utils.P* class but it happens because **Printing** class has no package definition. This means that the real full name of the class is **Printing**, but if you launch the java command from ~/JavaClasses folder, you are exactly stating that the full name of Printing class is **myname.practice.Printing**.

You have 2 options to fix this problem:

1) Declare the **myname.practice** package inside Printing class (I suggest this one)

2) Add the **myname.practice** folder to the classpath, in this way:

```java
~/JavaClasses$ java -cp myname.practice:. Printing
```

The `.` represents the current directory, and it is necessary so you can still reference the **myname.utils.P** class from ~/JavaClasses folder.

*Side note. At compile time you have no errors because probably you don't specify a classpath when you launch javac and so the current folder it is used. This way, myname.utils.P can be referenced without problem by every class, even by Printing.*

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not using the package name. Yes when java gives the error and the package name for class not found, it uses `/`. However those should be replaced with `.`. since parts of the package name are always separated with a period and never with a slash. So if I had a package `foo.bee`. Then when I tried to run

`java foo.bee`

It would run currently and all, however if I tried

`java foo/bee`

it would complain about a class not def error.